# How to expose windows file share via HTTPS and NTLM authentication?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, authentication, webdav

I want to be able to expose the contents of a windows file share via HTTP, so a file can be linked to using http:// rather than file:// which doesnt work in all popular browsers.

I want to be able to authenticate the user hitting the http:// url using NTLM (their credentials from their logged-in Windows session at their computer) and then "pass through" this authentication to the server to ensure that they are allowed to access the file share.

Have tried to set up IIS + WebDAV however I get this error:

```
Error: {Access Denied}
A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights.
```

Can what I want to do be done? Any guidance on the error I am running into?

Answer (score 0):

Hallo the computer or network service (depending the IIS user) needs read access at filesystem. Please check the security tab of our fo9lder which you want to access.